# Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Error! Missing Or invalid Module name

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, hardhat, verify

Cannot verify contracts using hardhat.
On running the command - `npx hardhat verify <contract_address> --network rinkeby`
I get a bunch of warnings like this -

```
Warning: Variable is shadowed in inline assembly by an instruction of the same name
   --> @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol:158:5:
    |
158 |     function add(Bytes32Set storage set, bytes32 value) internal returns (bool) {
    |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

and an error like -

```
Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Error! Missing Or invalid Module name
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

> npx hardhat verify --network rinkeby <contract_address>